# Django: keep log after deleting a foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

My question is simple:
I have a Folder model, and I have a Log model. Here are the simplified examples:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Log(models.Model):
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete="I NEED HELP HERE")
```

What this means is, A folder is created by a User, and each action done on the folder, is logged by using the Log model (user-edited folder, the user did this with folder, etc...)

What I want to do is simple: if some admin deletes the folder completely, I want to still keep the name of the folder. All actions in the on_delete attribute, do not let me do that.

Any ideas?

PS: those are not the real models, just an illustration of what I want to do. The real ones are 100+ lines of code :P

Comment: You can for example use `SET_NULL`. Or you might want to "soft delete" the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an answer, all I did was to set a default value, then put on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT.

The default value is a variable returned from a function, declared right above the model, taking the username and storing it in a different table.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own `on_delete` trigger, since the `on_delete` just expects a callable that will be called if the object to which it refers is deleted: Django does triggering management itself. But that will likely only make it more complicated.

I think it might be better to make `Folder` a "*soft-deleted*" model. Here in case you delete a model, it is not deleted from the database, but the database has a column with a boolean that specifies if the record is "deleted". If it is deleted, it will normally not be included in standard querysets on the model, but there are still ways to obtain the item to which it refers. Furthermore you can later recover a deleted object by "undeleting" it. You can for example make use of the [**`django-softdelete`** package [GitHub]](https://github.com/scoursen/django-softdelete).